# RabbitMQ Error 530 vhost not found with pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect to a remote rabbitmq server. I have the correct credentials and vhost exists on the remove server, but I cannot connect.
I get the error

> pika.exceptions.ProbableAccessDeniedError: (530, 'NOT_ALLOWED - vhost
>   test_vhost not found')

I have struggled with this for a while but I can't seem to get what the problem is.

Comment: Have you set permissions for the user you're trying to use?

Comment: Yes, the permissions have been set correctly for the user I'm trying to connect with

Comment: removing slash at the end in rmq connection string worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. On my local machine I am using rabbitmq version 3.5.7 while on the remote rabbitmq is on version 3.7.0

I had been declaring my vhost without a slash '/' on 3.5.2 and it has been working well but I realized that adding a slash before declaring the vhost worked on version 3.7.0 .
So now I use `/test_vhost` instead of just `test_vhost`

Comment: added a '/' and it worked :)

Comment: This is what worked for me too. Thanks. `f"pyamqp://{RABBITMQ_USER}:{RABBITMQ_PASS}@localhost/{RABBITMQ_VHOST}"`

Comment: Added // after the hostname. So from CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://usrename:pass@rabbitmq:5672/vhost' to  CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://usrename:pass@rabbitmq:5672//vhost'

Comment: when you create the vhost you need to add a slash? I'm confused.

Comment: @chovy you don't add the slash when creating it, you add it in the connection url

Answer (score 12):

For me,
before:

```
AMQP_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/hostname'
```

after:

```
AMQP_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672'
```

it works.

Comment: how to add url parameters like `heartbeat` if slash is removed at the end

Comment: @Perry you can keep the slash, just try 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/?heartbeat=30'